# Stored procedure return SELECT only with rows

Tags: sql-server-2008

I just set an SQL Stored Procedure to return a specific row in a specific order (from more to less important):

```
-- 1st Level -> Query a more detailed object...
SELECT ... WHERE something
-- if a result is find, the SP is returning the correct row.
-- if rowcount = 0 then, the SP is returning an empty row 
-- and continues with the next query (less specific than the 1st one).

IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
BEGIN
SELECT .... WHERE something else... 
 -- Again, if a result exists, the SP returns the correct row, but also 
 -- the result of the 1st query is returned without rows...
 IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
 BEGIN
 SELECT .... WHERE something else again...
 END
END
```

Is there any option to only return the SELECT statement that returns a non empty row? I don't want to return empty rows... and each time the row is an "sub-level" of the 1st query, I get empty results before the correct row.

I was thinking to create a table variable. Are there any better ways?

Comment: Are you ultimately only returning one row? Or is it possible that some of these queries will return multiple rows? And is the shape the same (e.g. same # of columns and compatible data types in each column)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are looking for the lack of rows why not use an if/else statement in your procedure. Something like:

```
If exists(/*firstQuery*/ SELECT ... WHERE something) begin
   SELECT ... WHERE something
end else if exists (/*secondQuery*/ SELECT .... WHERE something else... ) begin
   SELECT .... WHERE something else... 
end else /*Third query*/ begin
    SELECT .... WHERE something else again...
end
```

Just remember when checking is something exists you should select only one column (for example the id) as if you have calculated columns then this can slow down your procedure.

Comment: In exists it doesn't matter what you put in the SELECT list - SQL Server is smart enough to ignore it. I'd still suspect that repeating joins or where clauses for that query twice is going to have more of an impact than the column list would anyway.

Comment: True but I figured I would mention something about the columns just in case.

Comment: Also, in a stored procedure, you could probably just use `RETURN` after the first successful query, instead of bothering with extra `IF/ELSE` logic.